# Cascade data update in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a MySql table containing nodes sorted with a [modified preorder tree traversal](http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/) method. 
Each node has an id, a left value and a right value.

```
+---------+-----+-----+
| id      | lft | rgt |
+---------+-----+-----+
| root    | 1   | 20  |
| father1 | 2   | 7   |
| child1  | 3   | 4   |
| child2  | 5   | 6   |
| father2 | 8   | 9   |
| father3 | 10  | 17  |
| child3  | 11  | 12  |
| child4  | 13  | 14  |
| child5  | 15  | 16  |
| father4 | 18  | 19  |
+---------+-----+-----+
```

My goal is to bring `father1` after `father3`, and obtain this result.

```
+---------+-----+-----+
| id      | lft | rgt |
+---------+-----+-----+
| root    | 1   | 20  |
| father2 | 2   | 3   |
| father3 | 4   | 11  |
| child3  | 5   | 6   |
| child4  | 7   | 8   |
| child5  | 9   | 10  |
| father1 | 12  | 17  |
| child1  | 13  | 14  |
| child2  | 15  | 16  |
| father4 | 18  | 19  |
+---------+-----+-----+
```

To perform this operation I need to:

- increment `father1` (and descendants) left and right values of `10`
- decrement `father2` and `father3` (and descendants) left and right
  values of `6`

I'm trying to perform this update using PDO.

```
$left = 2; // father1 left value
$right = 7; // father1 right value
$drop = 18; // insert point value (will be after new father1 position)
$delta = $right - $left + 1; // 6 
$gap = $drop - $right - 1; // 10

$dbms->beginTransaction();

// increment father1 (and descendants)
$dbms->prepare("UPDATE categories SET lft=lft+:gaplft, rgt=rgt+:gaprgt WHERE lft>=:startlft AND lft<:endlft;");
$dbms->bindparam(':gaplft', $gap, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$dbms->bindparam(':gaprgt', $gap, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$dbms->bindparam(':startlft', $left, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$dbms->bindparam(':endlft', $right+1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$dbms->query();

// decrement father2 and father3 (and descendants)
$dbms->prepare("UPDATE categories SET lft=lft-:deltalft, rgt=rgt-:deltargt WHERE lft>=:startlft AND lft<:endlft;");
$dbms->bindparam(':deltalft', $delta, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$dbms->bindparam(':deltargt', $delta, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$dbms->bindparam(':startlft', $right+1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$dbms->bindparam(':endlft', $drop, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$dbms->query();

$dbms->commit();
```

This doesn't work as expected. This is the result:

```
+---------+-----+-----+
| id      | lft | rgt |
+---------+-----+-----+
| root    | 1   | 20  |
| father2 | 2   | 3   |
| father3 | 4   | 11  |
| child3  | 5   | 6   |
| child4  | 7   | 8   |
| child5  | 9   | 10  |
| father1 | 6   | 11  |  // should be 12 17
| child1  | 7   | 8   |  // should be 13 14
| child2  | 9   | 10  |  // should be 15 16
| father4 | 18  | 19  |
+---------+-----+-----+
```

I think this can be related to the concurrency of updates. After the first update, only `father1` (and descendants) are set to final value. The second update, which only should affect `father2` and `father3` (and descendants), actually affects `father1` too.

Is there a way to handle cascade updates in PDO?

Comment: At `$gap = $drop - $rgt - 1; // 10` shouldn't be `$gap = $drop - $right - 1; // 10`?

Comment: A `query()` and `commit()` call should block until it has been applied. I don't see any concurrency here. You have a transaction that encloses two sequential queries. If you want to focus these updates, why isn't `id` in the query conditions?

Comment: @rvbarreto: you're right. It's a typo because I've renamed variables when writing question. Corrected, thanks.

Comment: @tadman: because - thanks preorder tree traversal method - I can update group of nodes basing only on their left and right value. Example: if father1 has many descendants, I can easily update them simply knowing they are included between its left and right values (2 and 7). I think I have a concurrency because, after father1 increment, its values overlap with other fathers' values. And I think this is the reason why the snippet fails.

Comment: That's not exactly a concurrency problem, that's a cascade problem. Concurrency refers to two things happening in parallel.

Comment: Ok thanks for the precisation. I have edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some thoughts, I've realized that the required operation is equivalent to make a sum inside a circular interval.

If we consider the interval `(lft,rgt) = [2,18)`, add to all nodes (and descendants) a sufficient amount to position `father1` (and descendants) at the top of the interval `(18)`, we can obtain the required result. To make this we need to

1. calculate the amount needed to move `father1` (and descendants) to the top. This equals to the "distance" between `father1` and the top: `18-8 = 10`
2. add this amount to all nodes
3. translate all nodes down, to let the bottom of the interval coincide with `0`. In this case we need to subtract `2` from all nodes. This operation is needed for the next (important) step
4. make a `modulo` operation on all nodes. The `modulo` must have divisor equal to the width of the interval (in our case `18-2 = 16`). This allows `father2` and `father3` to exit from the top of the interval and re-enter from the bottom and leave `father1` untouched
5. translate the interval up again of `2` to re-establish the original bottom value

Let's have a look at the code to implement it.

```
$left = 2; // father1 left value
$right = 7; // father1 right value
$drop = 18; // insert point value
$gap = $drop - $right - $left - 1; // distance between father1 and the top, minus the initial offset (equal to the bottom of interval)
$size = $drop - $left; // 16, size of the interval

$dbms->prepare("UPDATE categories SET lft=:offsetlft+MOD(lft+:gaplft,:sizelft), rgt=:offsetrgt+MOD(rgt+:gaprgt,:sizergt) WHERE lft>=:startlft AND lft<:endlft;");
$dbms->bindparam(':offsetlft', $left, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$dbms->bindparam(':offsetrgt', $left, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$dbms->bindparam(':gaplft', $gap, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$dbms->bindparam(':gaprgt', $gap, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$dbms->bindparam(':sizelft', $size, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$dbms->bindparam(':sizergt', $size, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$dbms->bindparam(':startlft', $left, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$dbms->bindparam(':endlft', $drop, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$dbms->query();
```

Since we have a single query, we can remove `beginTransaction()` and `commit()` statements. And result is as expected

```
+---------+-----+-----+
| id      | lft | rgt |
+---------+-----+-----+
| root    | 1   | 20  |
| father2 | 2   | 3   |
| father3 | 4   | 11  |
| child3  | 5   | 6   |
| child4  | 7   | 8   |
| child5  | 9   | 10  |
| father1 | 12  | 17  |
| child1  | 13  | 14  |
| child2  | 15  | 16  |
| father4 | 18  | 19  |
+---------+-----+-----+
```

Simple and fast. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the same intervals on WHERE at both queries, that is the problem:

`WHERE lft>=:startlft AND lft<:endlft;`

So what is happening is that, on the first query, it adds `gap` to `father 1 left` -> 2+10 = 12. Father 1 left is now 12, as you wanted.
Then, on second query, instead of take `delta` from `father 2 left` and `father 3 left`, it takes `delta` from `father 1 left` -> 12-6 = 6. Father 1 left is now 6. The same happens with father 1 right, 7+10=17 then 17-6 = 11. The second query wont update father 2 and 3 because they didn't fit the interval provided on it.

You must correct the interval selected by WHERE on second query so it can updates Father 2 and 3 instead of update father 1. Change the second query to this one, this must do the trick.

```
// decrement father2 and father3 (and descendants)
$dbms->prepare("UPDATE categories SET lft=lft-:deltalft, rgt=rgt-:deltargt WHERE lft<:startlft OR lft>=:endlft;");
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but the intervals are disjointed. In the first query `startlft` is binded with `$left`, in the second with `$right+1`, so they have different values. A similar thinking can be done for `endlft` value.